# Why did the Rokka no Yuusha opening song change after episode 4?

Tags: music, rokka-no-yuusha

After episode 4, the opening song for Rokka no Yuusha changed from "Cry for the Truth" by Michi to "Black Swallowtail" by Uroboros and Tom H@ck.

Why did Passione (the studio) change the song? It seems weird since the visuals in the intro are the same and it's still the first season of this anime.

*Update: Episode 12 seems to use the first opening again.*

Comment: Have any new characters entered the intro perhaps? Maybe they wanted to hide them until the plot introduced them

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko I don't think so, the visuals are almost the same as with the first opening.

Answer (score 2):

"LOOK AT ALL THIS MONEY WE HAVE!!"
"Should we make more episodes?"
"Don't be ridiculous, 12 episodes is the anime standard!"
"So what should we do with the extra budget money?"
"What episode are we at again?"
"4"
"Okay, for the next one, CHANGE THE OPENING THEME!!"
"What about the visuals"
"Do we have enough money to change those too?"
"No..."
"Well those can stay the same."

And that is why something like that happens, there's no meaning behind it, they do it because they can.

To be honest, there might have been a disagreement from the start about the opening theme and they just decided halfway to switch, or maybe the majority didn't like the first theme so they decided to try to do what was best for the anime.  **All this to say, it has nothing to do with the anime itself, I watched it too, and nothing really changed from episode 4 to 5.**

Comment: Are you sure it was because they had extra budget money though? It also seems very possible they had some bond to the other artist and wanted to promote that song instead.

Comment: My point being it has nothing to do with the anime, and I also did say that they might have had a disagreement from the start about the opening theme. ie : they might have liked more than one band or as you said they had some bond to another artist.  The stuff at the beginning was just to show that it had nothing to do plot wise or had anything to do with the anime as a whole, the songs changing was unrelated and more or less, just because they could.